# Restoring sql table including identity column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We had a few tables have their data get deleted.

Now I have a copy database running where we were able to restore the lost data.  This is running in the same server instance.

However, the id columns are now out of sync. As some rows have obviously been deleted over time etc and so for example row 98 in the new table data is 98.  But maybe 101 in the old table.

Is it possible to copy all the data from the table across including the id? Or can I turn identity off from the column. Inert the data and then turn it back on.

I have tried the following code;

```
Truncate Table DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames 
Go

Set Identity_Insert DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames On

    Insert Into DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames
    Select * From LIVE_DB.dbo.UserNames

Set Identity_Insert DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames Off
```

However I get the error

> ```
> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> ```
>
> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: It looks like you need [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188059.aspx)

Comment: @VladimirBaranov thank you for this I found some code in another stack question however I get this error. any ideas please?

Comment: "when a column list is used". List all your columns explicitly instead of `*`.

Comment: There's around 30 columns in each of the tables. Is there no way around this? Also is this on both statements. Or just the insert or select?

Comment: I don't know any way around it. In SSMS right-click table and choose `Script table as` - `insert to` ...

Comment: @VladimirBaranov correct running and listing the columns worked. A bit of work but along with the link I posted worked with no hiccups at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the error more carefully:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>
> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Notice that it says “can only be used when a column list is used”. You are not using a column list in your `INSERT`. If you specified a column list, it should succeed. This would look something like:

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames ON;
INSERT INTO DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames (
     Id
    ,Column1
    ,Column2
) SELECT *
FROM LIVE_DB.dbo.UserNames;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DEV_DB.dbo.UserNames OFF;
```

It can be tedious to write that, however. You might want to generate the SQL statement with other code.

Answer (score -1):

What i do to avoid this is In a new table you are copying to do not make id an auto increment
copy the data over via a loop and the id will stay the same

create a separate table with one column (Not Auto Inc) and put the last record number in there

then when adding new records create a script to get the last number and increase it by one and use that number for the new record.

Never have an issue of losing id number then.

Comment: Ok can you be more specific i.e. provide some sample code for this.